# What good is the "Support" class in Battlefield 3? How do you play it effectively?

Tags: battlefield-3

**Assault** can heal and revive teammates.  **Recon** has a sniper-rifle.  **Engineer** can repair vehicles, and gets a rocket-launcher and proximity mines.  But **Support**, from what little I've played it, seems to just have extra ammo, which is not *nearly* as useful as every other class's specials.

What special things does **Support** do?  How do you effectively play as **Support**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The view of the classes you present in the question is way to simplistic.

**Support**

- Provides ammo. This is especially critical on big open maps with lot of armor. Most people play engineers using up their rockets really quickly;
- Having LMG with 3.4x + bipod, can provide accurate suppression fire at mid distance (upcoming patch is going to improve that);
- On rush maps can effectively suppress enemies preventing them from getting anywhere near m-coms. That can be done either with LMG + extended mags or with mortar (later is going to be nerfed in upcoming patch - 4.8s reload instead of 3.5s);
- Can run up to tanks and destroy them with C4, this is especially effective between buildings.

And BTW you say just *"Recon has a sniper-rifle"*, which is big understatement.

**Recon**

- Can set spawn point, which is quite important on rush (well placed, can allow whole squad to spawn within defenders' base time after time);
- Can set SOFLAM, which greatly increases effectiveness of Javelins, also allows Javelins to shoot down aircraft;
- Can use MAV to spot enemies far behind their lines. Then Support can pick them out with mortar.
- Can set T-UGS near m-com, allowing defenders to react before attackers get chance to arm it.

Comment: I still believe the Support class is strongly underpowered compared to the other classes, but this answer (despite having less upvotes) provides a better argument than the other one, so I'll award you the checkmark.

Comment: @BlueRaja: I wouldn't agree about being under-powered. LMGs are quite powerful and way more accurate than most assault rifles in the game. Also, apart of Engineer, Support is the only class that has any real chance at destroying tanks (either with C4 or mortar).

Comment: @BlueRaja: this is depending of the mode you are playing the most. Support is actually really good on most of the rush mode maps.

Answer (score 18):

First of all. Ammo is important. REALLY important. If you're support, hit 3. A LOT.

Secondly, the Support class is a master of laying down suppressing fire, and can keep people from popping out from behind that corner while the rest of your team moves up, or flanks them.

Thirdly, the support class later unlocks C4's (very handy for taking out tanks and other armored vehicles), claymores (useful for keeping your team from being flanked) and a mortar (very useful for defending an mcom or providing support for your squad).

To play support effectively, all you really need to do is deal out ammo around your team-mates. A support that actually hands out ammo will be noticed by others and commended (my proudest achievement so far is the resupply medal :P). Other than that, keep chokepoints bullet-ridden, and take out any armor that comes along (if you have c4).

All in all, while support may seem like it's got less to offer, it's actually a much more versatile class than any other, able to deal with almost any problem that comes along.

Also AMMO!

Comment: In my experience, ammo is really not important at all.  I've *never* run out of ammo, even after getting a dozen or so kills without dying.  You go back to full ammo when you die, but even if you manage to use up all your ammo without dying, there are usually plenty of weapons on the ground you could pick up.

Comment: My experience is that I burn through the ammo if things are going well and I'm on a bit of streak. I tend to reload after each kill which is probably wasteful. The ammo refill is always appreciated as I want to stick with the load out that is currently working for me. Plus, as an engineer I'll also need more secondary ammo for dealing with tanks and walls that get in my way.

Comment: mortar -- available only to support -- is also great for digging out a team of snipers. That really should be mentioned here.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: partially correct, however good snipers will shoot from much farther than range of mortar.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Have you ever played an engineer without the explosives perk?  I can go through my entire rocket supply in about 30 seconds if a couple tanks are incoming.

Comment: You forgot to mention AMMO!

Comment: Of course, 75% of the people playing support just never drop ammo...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, I would think you don't run out of ammo because the support people are doing their job. Every time you are near an ammo box your ammo is refilled. I would guess you get your ammo refilled all the time, maybe you're not just aware it is happening.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I often will run out of ammo when staying alive for a long period of time. This is especially true when laying down suppressive fire etc. Also engineers (and anyone throwing grenades or c4) can use the ammo to refill those rockets and explosives which can make them way more effective for anti-vehicles. I think that with what recon is limited to it is arguably the least useful class (especially with how some players play it only as a sniper from far back and not taking advantage of the perks it has)

Comment: I die long before I need more ammo :P That's 32/64 player maps though

Answer (score 0):

> How do you effectively play as Support?

I have been using the class to either defend my squad (e.g. Squad Deathmatch games) or an objective (namely Rush, but variants and Conquest can follow the same principle).

I would agree with anyone who says that they are not strong on the front line.  However, they really excel at... well, as their name suggests, providing support.

When it comes to aiding your squad drop ammo as much as you can.  At the same time, your mortars or other explosives to keep your flank and back safe.  As already mentioned in other answers, suppression fire can be pretty effective... but only when your squad is also attacking.  In other words, it isn't that effective if you are the last man standing in your squad.

If I end up in a squad with assault and recon (as I usually do) I switch to support to help my team win.

For objectives, I find C4 is a great tool for keeping enemies out of choke points and off objectives.  C4 around doorways, low ceilings and of course near MCOM stations.  Add in suppressive fire, you will make up a pretty effective defence.  Remember to throw down ammo when you can too.  Static defences tend to eat a lot of ammo when they are mowing down waves of attacker.