# What is the fastest way to level the Support class

Tags: battlefield-3

The other classes seem to be really easy to level in Battlefield 3, but how can I level an Support guy? All I seem to have is a rifle and some ammunition that nobody really takes?

Ultimately I want to become the revered "pipe canon noob"

Comment: see also: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39814/what-good-is-the-support-class-in-battlefield-3-how-do-you-play-it-effectivel

Answer (score 3):

The best way I have found is to play team-deathmatches. Because team-deathmatch has a more confined area you can easily kill enemies quickly to level up any of your classes. Also when you see an ally just drop an ammo box, that simple.

Comment: Not sure why this response got a down vote.

Answer (score 3):

1. Give Ammo Boxes
2. Use claymores to secure structures
3. Join a Squad
4. Follow the attack and defence orders for bonuses
5. Stick to your squad
6. Don't die

I prefer conquest and can get 250-300 points/minute, specially in Op Metro.

Almost forget: Play Op Metro Conquest and simply throw explosives, clays, and C4 and keep firing at the bottlenecks.

Answer (score 3):

- **play objectives**. Fist of all they are worth quite some points, one flag may be worth 450 pts (200 neutralize + 250 capture), one m-com is 600 (100 for setting, 500 on successful destroy); Secondly that's where the action is going to be.
- **drop ammo boxes** everywhere you see your teammates, even better squad-mates.
- **suppress choke-points** once you have M249 + ext. mags. you can get lots of kills and suppression assists that way, but...
- **don't camp far from action** - it's much better for your progression to have K/D 25/20 than 10/0.
- **play infantry maps**, Operation Metro, Seine Crossing and Grand Bazaar. Avoid huge maps like Caspian Border.

Answer (score 2):

Just play any game type and hop into a 4 man squad. Every squad supply gives you +10 more points than usual. If every time you spawn you drop and ammo box on whoever you spawn on you're guaranteed points. If the person is missing ANY ammo, a grenade or even one bullet you will get 30 points. With 3 people in your squad (if they are playing properly) you should be able to resupply them all for plenty of points to level up the class. Also the support weapon is extremely cheap and operates basically just as well as an assault rifle so don't be afraid to just mow people down haha. I find the support class to be one of the easier ones to level. If you're not in a squad just drop your ammo box in heavy traffic areas. Everyone needs ammo almost always!

Answer (score 0):

Play team death match with 64 players if possible and throw ammo boxes in areas where you know there is a lot of activity. You can also use C4 and claymores in these high-activity areas to get multiple kills and thus receive a higher bonus.

Weapons wise, I use the PKP or the M249 as they seem to be best suited (in my opinion) for close range combat. Noshahr Canals is a great TDM map.